# PHP - Extract value from query array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Do you have to use a loop to extract the value from a query array.

Query:

```
$fetchRegion = Singlequery("SELECT region FROM regions WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1",
                           array('id' => $_GET['region']),
                           $conn);
```

This is my array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["region"]=>
    string(10) "South West"
  }
}
```

I want to take the value and use it in another query, I didn't know if I had to use a foreach for example to get the value to use in my next query. The other stackoverflow questions that I saw used a loop

Comment: Rather than take that value and use it in another query, consider using a single query with a JOIN: What's the query that you want to use it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly and you want to acces to value then access it like so:

```
$fetchRegion[0]['region'];
```

You don't need to use foreach or any other loop since it will return at most one element because LIMIT 1 you used in query.

Comment: Can I use this to get a string and store it in another variable so for example $region = 'string from array';

Comment: Yes, you can ex. $region = $fetchRegion[0]['region'];

Answer (score 1):

Using loop :-

```
foreach($fetchRegion as $v) {
  $var = $v["region"];
}
```

or you get directly like:-

```
echo $fetchRegion[0]["region"];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to use a loop with that query because it will not return more than a single row. Instead, just check that you got a row back (it could return no results), and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that your result is going to look like that, `reset(reset($fetchRegion))` will give you the value 'south west'. It will behave badly if you don't get that exact format back though - for example, if the query does not return a row.